# What do the labels on drumsticks (5A, 7B, etc.) mean?

Tags: terminology, drums, equipment, drum-stick

There are different letters and numbers that different drumsticks carry, such as 5A, 7B. What do they represent? Does the material used (different woods, aluminium, etc.) have a bearing on the labelling?

Answer (score 13):

I have found the following information on [this](https://beatsure.com/drumstick-sizes/) website:

The letters will tell you the weight of the stick( A, B, S or D):

> A (orchestra) is the lightest type of stick out there. This was the
> type of drumstick used in an orchestra, but nowadays is used in a wide
> range of musical styles.
>
> B (band) is a medium weight stick – this kind of drumstick was used in
> concert bands. In more modern music, they make a great choice for rock
> drummers and people who are playing with a louder band.
>
> S (street) is a heavyweight stick – in a more traditional setting
> you’d use this stick in a marching band. It’s not as common to see
> this kind of stick out and about these days.
>
> D (dance) is also nowadays a bit of an oddity, but was traditionally
> used in dance bands. The 8D, which is the most popular stick of this
> kind, is a light and long stick.

The numbers will tell you the thickness of the sticks.

> The smaller the number, the thicker the stick.
>
> The larger the number, the thinner the stick.
>
> A stick with the number 7 would be pretty thin, whereas a stick with
> the number 2 would be pretty chunky. The most common numbers you’ll
> see on a stick are 2, 3, 5 and 7 – though there are also other
> possibilities out there.
>
> 5 is considered the standard choice in the drumming world – so it’s a
> great place to start.
>
> One strange exception to the numbering system is that a number 1 stick
> is longer, not thicker.
>
> If you see the same number repeated twice this normally
> means that it’s the same as a normal stick of the same number, but with
> something extra added, normally slightly more thickness or length.
>
> Manufacturers will sometimes put two different numbers on the stick –
> for example 85. This would be a stick that is somewhere in-between an
> 8 stick and a 5 stick.

Here is a picture reprensentation:

[image]

Here is a chart of some different combinations:

| Drumstick Sizes | Stick Length | Thickness | Suggested Styles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3S (Vater) | 17.25” | .730” | An absolute tree trunk of a drumstick. Sometimes used in drum corps |
| 2B | 16.25” | .630” | A thick log of a stick, for playing super loud and heavy |
| 5B | 16” | .595” | The classic stick choice for rock and louder styles |
| Extreme 5B | 16.5” | .595” | Same as a 5B – but slightly longer |
| Extreme 55B | 16.5″ | .610” | Like the Extreme 5B, but even fatter |
| 5A | 16” | .565” | The most popular stick in the world. A great all-rounder |
| Extreme 5A | 16.5” | .565” | Like a 5A, but a bit longer, for more reach and power |
| 55A | 16” | .580” | Halfway between a 5A and 5B. For someone who wants the best of both worlds |
| 3A | 16.19” | .580” | Like a 5A, but a little longer and fatter. Suits medium volume styles of music |
| 1A | 16.81” | .580” | Super long stick for easy reach around the kit |
| 7A | 15.5” | .540” | The classic stick choice for jazz and softer styles |
| 8D | 16” | .540” | Good for jazz and soft styles – longer than a 7A, making it easier to reach your drums |
| Extreme 8D | 16.5” | .540” | A longer version of the 8D |
| 85A | 16” | .550” | A blend of the 8D stick and the 5A stick. A lighter stick, but not too light |

As far as i can see, these labels won't explicitly tell you anything about the material they are made of.

Comment: There is an table like representation of the different wieghts and sizes, but i am not able to make a table like representation inside my answere. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Tables don't use html-style code, they're much simpler - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. I didn't know that detail. I added the table view of different combinations.

Comment: While it doesn't say anything about the material of the *stick*, I believe at least Vic Firth appends an `N` to designate a nylon *tip*, i.e. `5BN` would be a 5B stick with a nylon tip. I used to prefer playing nylon tipped sticks because it gives an interesting sound difference between pinging the ride cymbal with the tip vs. the broad side of the stick.